# memory game random color

Tags: java, arrays, memory, colors

Hey everybody I'm creating a memory game that uses a 4x4 2Darray.

I have the 4x4 filld with a pair of integers from 0-7 and they are randomly scattered. I want to assign a color to each pair, so when the mouse clicks over that square the assigned color will appear based on the integer and you will have to find the other integer based on it's corresponding matching color.
I've been running into some problems with this setColor method of mine. I'm going to include my whole code in case I messed up somewhere else and that was why. At the moment if I click every square once I use all 8 colors I assigned twice, but some of the colors don't match up to where the same integer is at on another tile. Also when I click the same tile multiple times it changes between 2-3 colors and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The parts I need advice on are the setColor method I have assigned and my logic behind it.

```
/*Sets the background of your memory board to black*/
public void init() 
{
    setSize(400,400);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    buildBoard(4);

}   
/*This is main in java applets
    You may need to add (not 
    change) a couple things in this method
 */
public void paint(Graphics canvas)
{
    if(firstRun) //for the first run we need to build our random board
    {

        print2DArray(board);
        buildBoard(4);
        firstRun = false;
    } 
    else // once our board is built we will display the game
    {
        displayGame(canvas);
        if (mouseClicked) // if the mouse has been clicked
        {
            displayHit(canvas);//find which box the user clicked
            mouseClicked = false;
        }
    }
}

/*
    DO NOT change this method
    determines if the mouse has been pressed
    sets x and y Mouse to the location of the mouse arrow
    redraws the image
 */
public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y ) 
{
    mouseClicked = true; 
    xMouse = x;
    yMouse = y;
    repaint();
    return true;
}

/*DO NOT change this method
    redraws the scene
 */

public void update ( Graphics g ) 
{
    paint(g);
}

/*
    pre: none
    post: build an array that holds the memory values for a board of size x size
    the board will hold two of each int from 0 to size randomly placed in the array
 */

public static void fillRect(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int length)
{
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    width = 100;
    length = 100;
    x = (int)xMouse/100;
    y = (int)yMouse/100;        
}

public void buildBoard(int s)

{
    int a = 4;
    for (int row = 0; row < a; row++)
        for (int column = 0; column < a; column++)
        {
            board[row][column] = count++ % 8;
        }
    for(int row = 0; row < 4; row++)

        for(int column = 0; column < 4; column ++) 
        {
            int x = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
            int y = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
            temp = board[row][column];
            board[row][column] = board[x][y];
            board[x][y] = temp;


        }
}
public static void print2DArray(int[][] arr)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}





public void displayGame(Graphics canvas)
{
    canvas.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    for(int i =0; i < 400; i+= WIDTH)
        for(int j = 0; j < 400; j+= WIDTH)
            canvas.drawRect(i, j, WIDTH, WIDTH);
}

/*
    Pre: xMouse and yMouse have been initialized
    Post: A circle is displayed in the correct box on the screen
    Currently the circle is displayed at the mouse location
 */
public void displayHit(Graphics g)
{

    /*int xGuess = (int)xMouse/100;
    int yGuess = (int)yMouse/100;
    board[xGuess][yGuess] = guess1;
    int xGuess2 = (int)xMouse/100;
    int yGuess2 = (int)yMouse/100;
    board[xGuess2][yGuess2] = guess2;

    if (guess1 == guess2)
    {
        setColor(g);
        centerHit(xMouse, yMouse);
        g.fillOval(xMouse, yMouse, 40, 40);
    }
    else 
    g.fillRect(guess1, guess2, width, length);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);*/
    setColor(g);
    centerHit(xMouse, yMouse);
    g.fillOval(xMouse, yMouse, 40, 40);
}

public void setColor(Graphics g)
{

    centerClick(x1,y1);     
    //int x = xMouse;
    //int y = yMouse;
    colorIndex = board[row][column];
    board[row][column] = board[x1][y1];
    board[x1][y1] = colorIndex;


    switch(colorIndex)
    {
    case 0: g.setColor(Color.RED);
    break;
    case 1: g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    break;
    case 2: g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    break;
    case 3: g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    break;
    case 4: g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    break;
    case 5: g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    break;
    case 6: g.setColor(Color.PINK);
    break;
    case 7: g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    break;
    }

}
public void centerHit(int centerX, int centerY)
{
    {
        if ((xMouse > 0) && (xMouse <=100))
            xMouse = 33;
        else if ((xMouse > 100) && (xMouse <=200))
            xMouse = 133;
        else if ((xMouse > 200) && (xMouse <=300))
            xMouse = 233;
        else if ((xMouse > 300) && (xMouse <=400))
            xMouse = 333;
    }
    {
        if ((yMouse > 0) && (yMouse <=100))
            yMouse = 33;
        else if ((yMouse > 100) && (yMouse <=200))
            yMouse = 133;
        else if ((yMouse > 200) && (yMouse <=300))
            yMouse = 233;
        else if ((yMouse > 300) && (yMouse <=400))
            yMouse = 333;
    }
}
public void centerClick(int centerX, int centerY)
{
    {
        if ((xMouse > 0) && (xMouse <=100))
            x1 = 0;
        else if ((xMouse > 100) && (xMouse <=200))
            x1 = 1;
        else if ((xMouse > 200) && (xMouse <=300))
            x1 = 2;
        else if ((xMouse > 300) && (xMouse <=400))
            x1 = 3;
    }
    {
        if ((yMouse > 0) && (yMouse <=100))
            y1 = 0;
        else if ((yMouse > 100) && (yMouse <=200))
            y1 = 1;
        else if ((yMouse > 200) && (yMouse <=300))
            y1 = 2;
        else if ((yMouse > 300) && (yMouse <=400))
            y1 = 3;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: im not sure what youre trying to do with three lines of code, heres what i think `colorIndex = board[row][column];` youre reading some cell's color, not sure which cell cuz i dont see where `column`or `row`values change. `board[row][column] = board[x1][y1];` seems to me like youre changing the original board, i dont think this is what you want and `board[x1][y1] = colorIndex;` assign last clicked cells color to clicked cell... mmmh, please explain these three lines _clearly_

Comment: @jambriz the board originally reads 0-7 and repeats 0-7 for the last two rows. I mixed up the rows and columns to randomize the numbers around. Those three lines of code were my attempt to use the mouse clicker to choose a block on the 4x4 2D array. Then use the xindex and yindex and find the corresponding array value at that point on board[row][column]. Then I will set that value at the index that was just clicked on through the switch statement to assign whatever color it is depending on it's integer value

Answer (score 2):

to keep the colors from changing, change this code

```
    colorIndex = board[row][column];
    board[row][column] = board[x1][y1];
    board[x1][y1] = colorIndex;
```

to

```
    colorIndex = board[x1][y1];
```

the color matching issue is because youre building the board twice: first on the firstRun of the `paint` method where you print the array and then on the `init`method where the board gets overwritten so you see different values

to solve it you should build the board only once in the `init` method, and call `print2DArray` afterwards to check it, so

```
 buildBoard(4);
 print2DArray(board); //<-- add this line to verify colors
```

and you could omit the `firstRun` flag and all associated code.

comment or delete this code:

```
/*if(firstRun) //for the first run we need to build our random board
    {
        print2DArray(board);
        buildBoard(4);


        firstRun = false;
    } 
    else // once our board is built we will display the game
    {*/
```

Comment: ok so that helps one of my problems. It prevents multiple color changes per click, but still my integers and assigned colors aren't matching up and I'm not sure why

Comment: could you also explain the difference between board[x1][y1] = colorIndex vs colorIndex = board[x1][y1] = colorIndex;

Comment: how are you checking if they match? they seem to match to me, anyway try changing `colorIndex = board[x1][y1];` to `colorIndex = board[y1][x1];` and see if thats what you want

Comment: the paired colors should match based on where they are on the 2Darray but they aren't and idk why

Comment: well the `=` operator is an assignment operator with Right to Left associativity, so when you do `x=y=x` youre first assigning `x` value to `y` and then `y`value to `x`, so at the end `x` remains unchanged, and `y` ends with the same value as `x`

Comment: ok so I've fixed that I just deleted the init() ones because my teacher doesn't want us to mess with the first run one.

Is this just a glitch sometimes I get 3 of the same color when I run this and click on all the boxes, and the boxes still don't seem to align properly with the colors and assigned integers